# Setting background color using java.awt.color

Tags: java, swing

This is my first Swing project on Eclipse, and I cannot set the background color of a component. I have tried by using this code :

```
B_Send.setBackground(new java.awt.color(0,0,255));
```

which returns the error:

> java.awt.color cannot be resolved to a type

Can anyone explain the error and why the code isn't working?

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: Since when you started coding, seems like you never use to practice much, cause if you do, such minute errors are a child's work. Though +1 for the input given the question, since it provides everything to be answered easily :-) In future practice more.

Answer (score 6):

It's not `java.awt.color` but rather `java.awt.Color`.

Yes, these little things mean a lot, and the Java compiler is extremely persnickety. Welcome to the world of programming.

Comment: Using an IDE will help a lot in debugging these little problems. It completes your code and says what errors you have, and why.

Comment: @Joost: he's using an IDE, Eclipse. Sometimes having two learning curves to climb is one too many.